# Running Excel Add-In Macro Based on Workbook Events

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that takes the user to the last previously active sheet. I need this macro to keep track of all previously active sheets, which it should be able to do automatically. I want to add this to an Excel add-in, since it needs to be compatible with all the worksheets that my company's using. The sheets themselves are not macro-enabled, so I can't have any code stored in the modules of ThisWorkbook.

I have tried out the examples that I've found on other websites. Unfortunately, all of them require using ThisWorkbook, which I won't be able to use. Is there a way to do this purely within an Excel add-in?

```
Public MyPrevSheet as String
Sub GoToPreviousSheet()
If Len(MyPrevSheet) > 0 Then
    Sheets(MyPrevSheet).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Previous
Else
    MsgBox "You have not switched sheets yet since opening the file!"
End If
End Sub
```

Ideally, I would like for MyPrevSheet to automatically track the last active sheet in the file.

Comment: Look up `Application Events`, here on SO, and on cpearson.com

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen, that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I managed to make it work using Application Events. The idea is to create a class module that can then be assigned the Application.

Here are some useful links that helped me: [http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx](https://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)

https://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/buildexceladdin05.asp